# Cookies not setting to variables from post form

Tags: php, cookies

```
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
  setcookie("names",0, 1);
setcookie("flavors",0, 1);
setcookie("scoops",0, 1);
header("Location: coookie.php");
exit();
  }

 if(isset($_POST['name'])&& ($_POST['flavor']) && ($_POST['scoop']))
{
setcookie("names", $_POST['name']);
setcookie("flavors", $_POST['flavor']);
setcookie("scoops", $_POST['scoop']);
header("Location: coookie.php");
exit();
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['names']) &&($_COOKIE['flavors']) &&($_COOKIE['scoops']))
{
 echo<<<_END
 <form action="coookie.php" method="post"><pre>
 enter your name.


 Name   <input type="text" name="name">
 </br>
Select Your Flavor 
    <select name="flavor">
<option value="choco">Chocolate</option>
<option value="van">Vanilla</option>
  </select>     
</br>

  <input type="radio" name="scoop" value="single" checked> Single Scoop<br>
  <input type="radio" name="scoop" value="double"> Double Scoop<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></pre>

  </form>
    _END;
}
       else
{
$name=$_COOKIE['names'];
$flavor=$_COOKIE['flavors'];
$scoop=$_COOKIE['scoop'];


echo<<<_END

hi $name Your order of $scoop $flavor ice-cream is on the way!

<form action="coookie.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="yes" name="delete">
<input type="submit" value="delete">
</body>
 _END;
}

?>
```

Error messages:

```
Undefined index: flavors line20
Undefined index: names   line 44
Undefined index: flavors line 45
Undefined index: scoops line 46
```

I keep getting the errors above and the "hi Your order of ice-cream is on the way!" as output.

Could you please explain how to resolve this error and how to set cookies to store the value for this code so I can display the data.

Comment: Undefined index: this means that the cookie is not being set... eventually, you can add an echo inside the if statement, where you are supposed to set the cookies, to see if the cookies are set. just echo any gibberish, like `echo "sadfjasdf";` just to see if it prints out or not. if it prints out, the conditions are met, if it does not, the conditions are not met. Also, why don't you use `$_COOKIE['variable'] = 'value';` instead of `setcookie()`?

Comment: I just used the `setcoookie()` after reading it in the php documentation. Also I did try to echo but it didnt work. @Hallur

Comment: If an echo doesn't work, that means that the condition of the if statement, isn't met. `if(isset($_POST['name'])&& ($_POST['flavor']) && ($_POST['scoop']))
{` meaning the error lies in that code. That being said, I will write an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested, to echo. It will show you whether or not an if statements condition is being met... let's take for example:

```
$a = true;

if ($a == true) {
echo "test";
}
```

> returns test

```
$a = "tru";

if ($a == true) {
echo "test";
}
```

> returns nothing

the error in your case, is on this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])&& ($_POST['flavor']) && ($_POST['scoop'])) { // this line
setcookie("names", $_POST['name']);
setcookie("flavors", $_POST['flavor']);
setcookie("scoops", $_POST['scoop']);
header("Location: coookie.php");
exit();
}
```

you check to see whether `$_POST['name']` is set and whether the value of `$_POST['flavor']` and `$_POST['scoop']` is `true`. Which in your case it is not. And this is also why the echo test, that I asked you to do in the comment section is not working, since the condition of the if statement is not met.

therefore, that line needs to be changed:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['flavor']) && isset($_POST['scoop'])) {
setcookie("names", $_POST['name']);
setcookie("flavors", $_POST['flavor']);
setcookie("scoops", $_POST['scoop']);
header("Location: coookie.php");
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *if* statement is missing the isset around two of the vars:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['names']) && !isset($_COOKIE['flavors']) &&(!isset($_COOKIE['scoops'])))
```

therefore your code fails on line 20 (the if) as it tries to read the 'flavor' cookie. Then it goes into the *else* and fails for all variables. Add the `isset` and you should see the content of the *if* as long as no cookies are set

Comment: The line 20 error is gone but Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), has occur for `$name`